# redirect to verify OTP page if server respond not verified

Tags: angular

In my project user must verify his account if isn't verified return error , i want catch the error and redirect to Verfiy page

this is my auth guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService,
    private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if(this._auth.loggedIn()) {
      return true
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/signup'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }})
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`router.navigate` inside guard won't work as expected.

```
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
}
```

From [**`canActivate`**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) method you can return `UrlTree` if you want to redirect from guard by using `createUrlTree` method.

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if(this._auth.loggedIn()) {
      return true
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/signup'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }})
      return this._router.createUrlTree('/signup', {
         queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url },
      });
    }
}
```